# Are Node MCU or Wemos D1 mini stable

Tags: esp8266

To give some background, I created a WiFi IoT device using ESP 11E/F. I was doing basic stabilization using capacitors and resistors, and although some chips mostly were working okay, some chips (~50%) definitely faced random reboots quite frequently (~every 15-30 min). This led me to question if the bare bones stabilization circuit I was using was sufficient or not, and also if the ESP 8266 I was getting (It said AI Thinker) was correct.

So I started to check some chips like Wemos D1 mini and [NodeMCU](https://robu.in/product/d1-mini-v2-nodemcu-4m-bytes-lua-wifi-internet-of-things-development-board-based-esp8266/) are what would provide better stabilization circuits.

I'm not doing any heavy lifting, basic API hits and keepalives and stuff using micropython firmware. Nothing that I'd call CPU intensive.

Are these chips stable? Can I rely on them and productionize the devices I'm making? How well are these chips being used (and if not, are there other ESP based boards in US$ 3-6 price range which are stable?).

Comment: You probably should connect their serial port and capture whatever they say when they reboot to better understand why they do it. Also, are you using a watchdog timer?

Comment: No I'm not using watchdog timer @jcaron. The thing is it works for a lot of chips. However, would greatly appreciate if you could let me know if Wemos/NodeMCU are stable for production.

Comment: I have no idea, though in many cases it's often more a matter of firmware versions rather than hardware issues. But without a capture of what they say when they reboot, it's difficult to say anything on the topic.